# How do I set Sum on the totals row of an Excel table in Powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm writing a script to edit a CSV, put all the data into three tabs and create a table on each tab with a "Totals" row. I'm new to PS but everything is done and working, except I can't do anything with the "Totals" row, i.e. I can't select Sum or Count or what have you for the column totals.

The last thing I tried was:

```
$Worksheet.ListObjects("Table_Name").ListColumns("Column_Name").TotalsCalculation = xlTotalsCalculationSum
```

which give me:

> Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain
>   a method named  'ListObjects'.

Can anyone tell me where I can find a comprehensive reference for Excel com object methods?

Comment: It sounds like $Worksheet is not properly assigned but you didn't think that portion of the PS script was important enough to include.